# Having trouble with setting width of div with css

Tags: html, css

When I use this code with JSFiddle it works fine, but in safari it doesn't work properly. Not sure what the problem is since it seems pretty basic. The problem is that the right side of the chat box in the middle goes over too far.

Screenshot of problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6yxw.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/XC4cg/

```
<body>
    <div class="chat">
        <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <div class="chat-messages">
            <div class="chat-message">
                Alex: Hello there
            </div>
            <div class="chat-message">
                Billy: Hello!
            </div>

        </div>
        <textarea placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
        <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body,
textarea,
input {
    font: 13px "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

.chat {
    max-width: 300px;
}

.chat-messages,
.chat textarea,
.chat-name {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.chat-messages {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
}

chat-message {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.chat-name{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.chat textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-top:0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.chat-status{
    color: #bbb;
}

.chat textarea,
.chat-name {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Try this width: 100% !important;

Answer (score 0):

I don't have safari on my laptop, but I suspect that this is a [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) issue.

This should do the trick:

```
.chat-messages {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
```